# Using media queries for html emails using python flask/jinja

Tags: python, flask, media-queries, html-email, jinja2

I want to use `media queries` for the html emails I generate using `jinja`. The issue is that I am forced to put CSS inline for the emails for the CSS to be recognized, and media queries apparently cannot be put inline. Is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good solution. You can put the media queries inside an `<style>` tag but we aware that gmail doesn't support them. Gmail requires all styles to be inline, [this tool](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) could be helpful

Comment: Do you know how mailchimp is able to resize the emails on the mobile clients? It seems that they are using media queries...not sure how they are getting it to work.

Comment: I think they use a fluid layout and some tricks. Check out this http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-simple-responsive-html-email--webdesign-12978

Answer (score 0):

CSS support varies greatly depending on which email client you are using. I would suggest having a look at [The Ultimate Guide to CSS](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) (please click "Download the poster" to get the full one). As you can see clients like Gmail are very limited in what they allow. AFAIK there is no solution for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Got it, thanks! On the iphone mail client, the email text is showing up extremely small -- is there a good solution to fix this?